# ¿Cómo desarrollar una red LSTM con más de una serie de tiempo?

Tags: python, lstm

Estoy trabajando con una base de datos que tiene variables con diferente cantidad de datos y además que se tomaron mediciones 2205 veces, entonces tengo 2205 series de tiempo y no sé como podría meterlas a la red LSTM para entrenarla. Veo que siempre trabajan con una sola serie temporal, al menos en los tutoriales.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!